# Mobile First Platform v 7.1 cannot register the devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have done the installation and configuration of MFP 7.1V with WAS 8.5.5.0 V successfully.Here we are able to access the operation and analytics console and able to add the application (.wlapp files) and adapter files and able to access those application in tab by instantiating an apk files in the tab.

But here the issue we are facing is we are not able to get the devices list in the operation console and analytics and devices tracking in the analytics console.

Comment: Pre-requisite minimum for MFPF 7.1 is 8.5.5.3. You should consider that
1) Do you see error messages in the system logs?
2) If you query your DB and DEVICES table, do you see entries?
3) Are your application able to connect to the server successfully and invoke adapters?

Comment: So you can deploy the app successfully, but what do you mean by "not able to get the devices list"?

Answer (score 0):

So essentially I guess the issue is that the applications fail to connect to the server at all. Please edit your question with the **full** client-side log with the errors.

Until then my suggest is to verify in the generate .plist/.properties file that you are indeed attempting to connect to the correct server. Verify the host, port and context-root values in the files.